How to connect Laradock to an external LDAP server
I have a Laravel 10 project which is based on laradock (cloned from https://github.com/Laradock/laradock). I'd like to connect the laravel application with an external LDAP server which does contain the users authorized to connect to my application.
I read a lot about docker's external networks but I haven't found the way to set them in laradock's docker-compose.yml.
Can anyone give me a hint please ?
I used
docker-compose up -d --build apache2 phpmyadmin 

to create the containers listed below
Creating laradock_mariadb_1          ... done
Creating laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
Creating laradock_workspace_1        ... done
Creating laradock_phpmyadmin_1       ... done
Creating laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
Creating laradock_apache2_1          ... done


I tried to declare a "ldap" network at the beginning of the docker-compose.yml using the bridge driver
version : "3"
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  ldap:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

and then call the network in the containers "workspace" and "php-fpm"
networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
        - ldap

I can ping the LDAP server from the workspace container

If anyone comes across the same problem I eventually found the answer.
The problem was due to the certificate of the LDAP server which was auto-assigned.
Therefore I had to write TLS_REQCERT never in the /etc/ldap/ldap.conf of the php-fpm container.
I therefore wrote the following line in the laradock/php-fpm/Dockerfile


    ###########################################################################
    # LDAP:
    ###########################################################################
    
    ARG INSTALL_LDAP=true
    
    RUN if [ ${INSTALL_LDAP} = true ]; then \
        apt-get install -yqq libldap2-dev && \
        ARCH=$(arch)   && \
        docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir="lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/" && \
        docker-php-ext-install ldap && \
        mkdir /etc/ldap && \
        echo "TLS_REQCERT never" >> /etc/ldap/ldap.conf \
    ;fi

And then rebuild the containers
Et voilà
